# Relation between filtrations of stochastic processes

Tags: stochastic-processes, filtrations

We consider a stochastic process $X_t$ that takes values in $\mathbb{R}$.

Now we consider the following processes:
$U_t = X_t + t$, $W_t = X_t^2$, $Y_t = \sin(X_t^2)$, $Z_t = e^{X_t}$.

Their natural filtrations we denote by $\mathcal{F}^X$, $\mathcal{F}^U$, $\mathcal{F}^W$, $\mathcal{F}^Y$, $\mathcal{F}^Z$.

The question is: What is the relation between these filtrations, i.e. which are stronger and which are weaker to the others.

I have some basic background about stochastic processes, but this problem is too theoretical for me.

Comment: What is your progress?

Comment: My intuition is that $\mathcal{F}^Y$ is the weakest, then we have $\mathcal{F}^W$, and then $\mathcal{F}^U$, $\mathcal{F}^Z$, $\mathcal{F}^X$ are equal.